# Android app is consistently loading old questions when visiting a site from the sidebar

Tags: bug, android-app, question-lists

I'm using Android App version 1.0.23 on a HTC Velocity 4G running Android 4.0.3.

Consistently, when I navigate to a question from the sidebar, the Android app will load up an old version of the question list, and I'll have to refresh it to see the updated question. I'll try to illustrate:

The question list, after refreshing:

[image: recent questions]

Recent questions! Perfect. If I visit a question then hit back to return to this view, I'll see these same questions. Great!

But if I choose to navigate to this page through selecting the sidebar... it'll load up the following set of questions, which are two days old. Please be aware **I am scrolled to the top**; I have not scrolled down at all.

[image: old questions from 2 days ago]

If I refresh, I'll see the new questions again as I should. But next time I navigate back to this site via the sidebar, I'll see these old questions again.

This behaviour is consistent for visiting other sites via the sidebar.

Comment: No repro on Nexus 4, Android 4.4.2, app 1.0.23. Every time I open the site from sidebar, it will reload the questions just like refreshing manually, then showing the latest activities.

Comment: Now that I'm back on a HTC One running Android 4.4.2 app version 1.0.26 I'm not getting this issue.